# Why aren't the current kernel headers available via apt-get

Tags: raspbian, driver, apt

I am trying to compile some usb drivers for the pi and therefore, I need to get the headers that correspond to my present kernel

`uname -r` produces `4.1.7+`

Based on my experiences with Debian and Ubuntu based systems, I assumed that `apt-get install linux-headers-rpi` would get me the relevant headers, but lo and behold, that meta package gets me `linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common` which is not exactly what I was expecting.

Could someone explain why I have to go [rummaging about on the net](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/) for the headers for the current image?

Comment: This is driving me batty too.  A USB Wifi dongle I got requires compiling its driver, but since several of the Pi kernels do not have matching headers in the repo, I have to roll back to an older kernel.  Since I don't know how to roll back without re-imaging (simple installing the old kernel doesn't magically make it active), it's becoming a PITA...